# Why doesn't this quoted form evaluate as expected

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a simple function that works:

```
(defun ifelse (the-test)
  (cond (the-test (format t "passed test, true!"))
    (t (format t "failed test, boo hoo"))))
```

If I do this, I get what you'd expect:

```
(ifelse  (funcall (lambda () nil)))
failed test, boo hoo
NIL
```

I'm curious why this doesn't also result in a "failure" :

```
CL-USER> (ifelse  '(funcall (lambda () nil)))
passed test, true!
NIL
```

My thinking is that, rather than evaluating the `funcall` in place and then passing the return value into `ifelse`, the entire `funcall` is being passed unevaluated into the `ifelse` -- however, how is a quoted form treated within the function? Wouldn't it be essentially copied in-place and then treated as a true Lisp form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example , you pass a list as argument (because of the quote).
You need to use eval to evaluate the quoted list to have the 'failure'.
like this

```
(ifelse  (eval '(funcall (lambda () nil))))
```

or remove the quote

```
(ifelse  (funcall (lambda () nil)))
```

Comment: I would recommend against using `eval` here. First of all, you don't need it: why would you want to pass a list in, and expect it to be evaluated? That's silly. The built-in `if` doesn't work that way. You open yourself up to things like not being able to access variables defined elsewhere in the code. The reason the quoted list isn't false isn't "because you need eval"; the reason is "because you passed it a list, and lists are truthy".

Answer (score 4):

Let's see what you actually get:

```
(defun return-argument (element) element)

[9]> (defun return-argument (element) element)
RETURN-ARGUMENT
[10]> (return-argument (funcall (lambda () nil)))
NIL
```

Ok, this is as expected. Now your second function call, which results in a failure.

```
[11]> (return-argument '(funcall (lambda () nil)))
(FUNCALL (LAMBDA NIL NIL))
```

Aha, this gives us a clue. We're not evaluating argument, because it's quoted. In fact, we can see we're getting it back as a list:

```
[19]> (listp (return-argument '(funcall (lambda () nil))))
T
```

Remember, when you quote something, you prevent it from being evaluated.

Note: `return-argument` is the same function as the built-in `identity`. I wrote a new one so you could see what it's doing under the hood.